# objective-c (iphone sdk) access instance method from separate class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, instance

I know this is a pretty well posted thing to do, but I still can't work it out.

I have an instance method saveAllDataJobs in Jobs.m.

```
- (void) saveAllDataJobs { ... }
```

I am in DetailViewController.m and I want to run the method saveAllDataJobs, which is in Jobs.m.
What precisely do I need in order for this code to run.

Sorry for the repeat question, but I can't work it out.

Regards

Comment: An instance of class Jobs. Then [jobs saveAllDataJobs];

Comment: no, thats not right. Thats for a class method (the +), not the instance method (The -) one. I was looking for a litle more than one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about **"delegation"** in documents. Here is the basics:

When you create DetailViewController, you give it an ivar:

```
@interface DetailViewController {
    id delegate;
}

@property (assign) delegate;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize delegate;

@end
```

Then:

```
DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName...]
controller.delegate = jobs; // "jobs" is of class Jobs, instantiated somewhere else
```

Later, when you need to call some method on jobs inside detailViewController, you do

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(saveAllDataJobs)]) {
    [self.delegate saveAllDataJobs];
}
```

There are more details around this, but this is the basic pattern.

Comment: thats going to take some deciphering. thanks for your help this far, now i need to try and figure it out.

Comment: The basic idea is this: whoever creates the "controller" object also gives it reference to "jobs" object, so "controller" knows how to call methods on "jobs".

Answer (score 0):

Call the method with `[someJobsInstance saveAllDataJobs]` ?

Is that is not an answer to your question then you need to explain more what you are trying to accomplish. I get the feeling that this is more about application architecture than about calling methods.

Comment: can you explain the someJobsInstance bit. That is what I am having trouble with.
OTherwise I can post more elaborate code.