# Properly declare delegation in Objective C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, methods

Ok, This has been explained a few times (I got most of the way there using [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155256/objective-c-iphone-sdk-access-instance-method-from-separate-class)), but I am missing something. I am able to compile cleanly, and able to set the delegate as well as call methods from the delegate, but I'm getting a warning on build:

```
No definition of protocol 'DetailViewControllerDelegate' is found
```

I have a DetailViewController and a RootViewController only. I am calling a method in RootViewController from DetailViewController. I have the delegate set up as so:

In `RootViewController.h`:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, DetailViewControllerDelegate> //Error shows up here
{
//Some Stuff Here
}
//Some other stuff here
@end
```

In `RootViewController.m` I define the delegate when I create the view using `detailViewController.delegate = self`

In `DetailViewController.h`:

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate;

#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate

//some methods that reside in RootViewController.m

@end
```

I feel weird about declaring the protocol above the import in `DetailViewController.h`, but if I don't it doesn't build. Like I said, the methods are called fine, and there are no other errors going on. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pheelicks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264257/pheelicks) is pretty much there but it looks like some of your protocol methods also use the `DetailViewController` class, I imagine it looks something like this :

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) controller:(DetailViewController *)controller hasSomething:(id)thing;
@end

@class DetailViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

and you haven't defined `DetailViewController` yet so you will get an error in the protocol definition.

You can fix this in two ways :

a) Declare (but don't define yet) the class before the protocol

```
@class DetailViewController;

@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) controller:(DetailViewController *)controller hasSomething:(id)thing;
@end
```

b) Just use `UITableViewController` instead of `DetailViewController` in your protocol methods.

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) controller:(UITableViewController *)controller hasSomething:(id)thing;
@end
```

Personally, I choose solution (a) but it really depends on what you're trying to do.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

In DetailViewController.h:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"    

@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

//some methods that reside in RootViewController.m

@end

@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
  id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Comment: When I do that, I end up with errors in the method on build. So I get `Expected ')' before DetailViewController`. The method doesn't have any typos in it.

-EDIT TO ADD-

It does get rid of the warning though.

Comment: Try moving the import to before the protocol (see updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you could tackle this, similar to the solution proposed by deanWombourne.

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate;

@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) controller:(DetailViewController *)controller hasSomething:(id)thing;
@end
```